# VueJS: Best way to Cache http response data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm finding a **best way to Cache http response data in VueJS**, Now I use Vuex Store to my Blog. I want to cache all response data when it requested into server.

Specifically, this is my blog:

When I request data by router to blog detail with **1, 3, 4**, I have response data. How can I cache it and then I **re-route to 1, 3, 4 in the same session**, it not re-fetch data and get data cache to display?

Now I use Vuex and I think it slow if has to store too many data.

[image]

Comment: Vuex is not slow. Slow is fetching the data from API again and again. Do you use `<keep-alive><router-view /></keep-alive>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker) were built for this. They can intercept and cache all requests made on your page. With a little extra work, you can easily add offline capabilities.

You can also use the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) with `window.caches`, mind the browser support though.

Another way is to use LocalStorage/IndexedDB to manually store your responses, but that's more work.

Comment: Does Instagram use service workers, bro? Can we checked it?

Comment: Redis is an option.

Comment: @Eric can you elaborate your 3rd option of doing this? I know it is resolved question but i have same kind of situation. How do you achieve it? Please help me on same situation. Here is my open thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296962/cached-network-requests-and-get-the-cached-response-for-calling-same-request?noredirect=1#comment113696550_64296962]

Comment: @Wayne Redis is not a front-end/client-side option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [swrv](https://docs-swrv.netlify.app) to cache your response. swrv use Vue Composition API hooks for remote data fetching.
if you got vue2, then need [@vue/composition-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/composition-api) to make them work.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34465302)