# API consumption and pre-consumption

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am a beginner on "vuejs", on one of my pages of my app, I created 4 "tabs", each having a route.
Concretely, I have a page Salarié, with 4 tabs: File, Salaries, Statistics, Appreciations.
Each tab has its own route and consumes a different API or at least different methods from my API.

My problem is overconsumption of this API and a desire to optimize loading times.

Clearly, when I load my tab Folder, I consume the corresponding api, if I click on the tab Salaries, I consume a second API, if I return to the tab Folder, I rebuild the first API while the information are strictly identical.

Optimally, I would like:

- Consume my API "Folder" to the consultation of the file
- The data resulting from the consumption of the API "Folder" remains "in memory", in order to be able to be resumed if i return on this tab, without making a call to the API.
- I "pre-consume", while viewing the folder tab, the other APIs to speed up loading.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535485/vuejs-best-way-to-cache-http-response-data

Comment: Thanks, using vuex, the API is no longer requested after the first use.